# Can I hide the api url from the browser network panel or console?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I am logging in my react app, if I put wrong credentials, in the console I am seeing this

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)
```

But I am not logging it anywhere in backend or frontend. So, my question is why I am having this, what is the mistake and what can I do to solve this? I am using axios.

Comment: That's just your browser displaying requests in the console and network tab

Comment: You can't hide it.

Comment: So, app user can always see what api url i am hitting to get the data? Isn't it bad ?

Comment: That's absolutely normal, nothing you can do about it. And no, not bad.

Comment: @TanmoySen Since network calls are public. Its on you to maintain security on these.